# Examining $\int_0^1 \left(\frac{x - 1}{\ln(x)} \right)^n\:dx$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, definite-integrals, special-functions

I'm currently working on the following family of integrals:
\begin{equation}
 I_n = \int_0^1 \left(\frac{x - 1}{\ln(x)} \right)^n\:dx
\end{equation} 
Where $n \in \mathbb{N}$. I employed Feynman's Trick coupled with the Dominated Convergence Theorem and Leibniz's Integral Rule. In doing so, I introduced the following function:
\begin{equation}
 J_n(t) = \int_0^1 \left(\frac{x^t - 1}{\ln(x)} \right)^n\:dx
\end{equation}
Where $0 \leq t \leq 1 \subset \mathbb{R}$.  With some fairly easy steps, I end up with the following ODE:
\begin{equation}
    J_n^n(t) =  (-1)^n \sum_{j = 1}^n {n \choose j} (-1)^j \frac{j^n}{jt + 1}   \nonumber
\end{equation}
Where $J_n^k(t)$ is the $k$-th derivative of $J_n(t)$ with the conditions $J_n^k(0) = 0$ for $ 0 \leq k \leq n$. As such, to resolve $J_n(t)$ I need to integrate $J_n^n(t)$ $n$ times whilst applying the initial conditions. Although I can do it for any fixed $n$, I'm yet to be able to generalise it for any $n$. I was wondering if anyone has working with this type of ODE and if so, is there any preferable ways to approach it?

Initially I thought that using Laplace Transforms would be ideal as in applying it to $J_n^n(t)$ all terms would be removed given the initial condition. This felt apart as the Laplace Transform of $\frac{1}{t + a}$ is a nasty Special Function to work with.

So, to repeat, is there an approach people can recommend?

---

For anyone who may be interested, here is my work on this integral:

In this section, I would like to address the following family of integrals:
\begin{equation}
    I_n = \int_0^1 \left( \frac{x - 1}{\ln(x)} \right)^n \:dx \nonumber 
\end{equation}0
To begin with, consider the case when $n = 1$:
\begin{equation}
    I_1 = \int_0^1 \frac{x - 1}{\ln(x)}\:dx \nonumber 
\end{equation}
Here we introduce the function:
\begin{equation}
    J_1(t) = \int_0^1 \frac{x^t - 1}{\ln(x)}\:dx \nonumber 
\end{equation}
We observe that $I_1 = J_1(1)$ and $J_1(0) = 0$. Here we employ Leibniz's  Integral Rule and differentiate under the curve with respect to $t$:
\begin{equation}
    J_1'(t) = \int_0^1 \frac{\frac{d}{dt}\left[x^t - 1 \right]}{\ln(x)}\:dx = \int_0^1 \frac{\ln(x)x^t}{\ln(x)}\:dx = \int_0^1 x^t \:dx = \left[ \frac{x^{t  +1}}{t + 1}\right]_0^1 = \frac{1}{t + 1} \nonumber 
\end{equation}
We now integrate with respect to $t$:
\begin{equation}
    J_1(t) = \int \frac{1}{t + 1} \:dt = \ln\left|t + 1 \right| + C \nonumber 
\end{equation}
Where $C$ is the constant of integration. To resolve $C$ we employ $J_1(0) = 0$:
\begin{equation}
    J_1(0) = 0 = \ln\left|0 + 1\right| + C \rightarrow C = 0 \nonumber
\end{equation}
Thus, 
\begin{equation}
    J_1(t) = \ln\left|t + 1\right| \nonumber
\end{equation}
We now resolve $I_1$ using $I_1 = J_1(1)$:
\begin{equation}
    I_1 = J_1(1) = \ln\left|1 + 1\right| = \ln\left|2\right| \nonumber 
\end{equation}
The question I have is: Can this approach be used for other or all values of $n$?. To address this, I will proceed by applying the same method to $n = 2$:
\begin{equation}
    I_2 = \int_0^1  \frac{\left(x - 1 \right)^2}{\ln^2(x)}\:dx \nonumber
\end{equation}
We introduce the function:
\begin{equation}
    J_2(t) = \int_0^1 \frac{\left( x^t - 1\right)^2}{\ln^2(x)}\:dx \nonumber
\end{equation}
We observe that $I_2 = J_2(1)$ and $J_2(0) = 0$. We proceed here by employ Leibniz's Integral Rule and differentiate under the curve with respect to $t$:
\begin{equation}
    J_2'(t) = \int_0^1 \frac{\frac{d}{dt}\left[\left(x^t - 1\right)^2 \right]}{\ln^2(x)}\:dx = \int_0^1 \frac{2\left(x^t - 1\right)\ln(x)x^t}{\ln^2(x)}\:dx = 2 \int_0^1 \frac{x^t\left(x^t - 1\right)}{\ln(x)}\:dx \nonumber 
\end{equation}
We observe that $J_2'(0) = 0$. We now differentiate again with respect to $t$:
\begin{equation}
    J_2''(t) = 2\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(x)x^t\cdot \left(x^t - 1\right) + x^t \cdot \ln(x)x^t}{\ln(x)}\:dx = 2\int_0^1 2x^{2t} - x^t \:dx = 2\left[\frac{2x^{2t + 1}}{2t + 1 } - \frac{x^{t + 1}}{t + 1} \right]_0^1 = 2\left[\frac{2}{2t + 1} - \frac{1}{t + 1}\right] \nonumber 
\end{equation}
We now integrate with respect to $t$:
\begin{equation}
    J_2'(t) = 2\int \frac{2}{2t + 1} - \frac{1}{t + 1} \:dt =2\bigg[ \ln\left|2t + 1\right| - \ln\left|t + 1\right| \bigg]  + C \nonumber 
\end{equation}
Where $C$ is the constant of integration. To resolve $C$, we use $J_2'(0) = 0$:
\begin{equation}
    J_2'(0) = 0 = 2\bigg[\ln\left|2\cdot 0 + 1\right| - \ln\left|0 + 1\right|\bigg] + C = 0 + C \rightarrow C = 0 \nonumber
\end{equation}
Thus, 
\begin{equation}
    J_2'(t) = 2\bigg[\ln\left|2t + 1\right| - \ln\left|t + 1\right|\bigg] \nonumber \nonumber 
\end{equation}
We now integrate again with respect to $t$:
\begin{equation}
    J_2(t) = 2\int  \ln\left|2t + 1\right| - \ln\left|t + 1\right| \:dt = 2\bigg[\left(\frac{2t + 1}{2}\right)\bigg[ \ln\left|2t + 1\right| - 1 \bigg] - \bigg[ \left(t + 1\right)\ln\left|t + 1\right| - t \bigg] \bigg] + D \nonumber 
\end{equation}
 Where $D$ is the constant of integration. To resolve $D$ we use the condition $J_2(0) = 0$:
 \begin{equation}
     J_2(0) = 0 = 2\bigg[\left(\frac{2\cdot 0 + 1}{2}\right)\bigg[ \ln\left|2\cdot 0 + 1\right| - 1 \bigg] - \bigg[ \left(0 + 1\right)\ln\left|0 + 1\right| - 0 \bigg]\bigg] + D   = -1+ D \rightarrow D = 1 \nonumber 
 \end{equation}
 Thus, 
 \begin{equation}
     J_2(t) = 2\bigg[\left(\frac{2t + 1}{2}\right)\bigg[ \ln\left|2t + 1\right| - 1 \bigg] - \bigg[ \left(t + 1\right)\ln\left|t + 1\right| - t \bigg]\bigg] + 1 \nonumber = \left(2t + 1\right)\ln\left|2t + 1\right| -2\left(t  + 1\right)\ln\left|t + 1\right| \nonumber 
 \end{equation}
 Thus, we now may resolve $I_2$ using $I_2 = J_2(1)$:
 \begin{equation}
     I_2 = J_2(1) = \left( 2\cdot 1 + 1\right)\ln\left|2\cdot 1 + 1\right| -2 \left(1 + 1\right)\ln\left|1 + 1\right| = 3\ln(3) -4\ln(2) \nonumber 
\end{equation}
Here I will attempt to resolve the integral in it's general form. I will employ the same approach as for $n = 1, 2$ and introduce the function:
\begin{equation}
    J_n(t) = \int_0^1 \frac{\left(x^t - 1 \right)^n}{\ln^n(x)}\:dx \nonumber 
\end{equation}
We observe that $I_n = J_n(1)$ and $J_n(0) = 0$. We begin by expanding the integrand's numerator using the Binomail Expansion:
\begin{equation}
    J_n(t) = \int_0^1 \frac{\sum_{j = 0}^n { n \choose j} \left(x^t\right)^j \left(-1 \right)^{n - j}}{\ln^n(x)}\:dx = (-1)^n \sum_{j = 0}^n {n \choose j} (-1)^j \int_0^1 \frac{x^{jt}}{\ln^n(x)}\:dx \nonumber
\end{equation}
Taking the same approach as before, we now employ Leibniz's Integral Rule and differentiate $n$ times under the curve with respect to $t$:
\begin{equation}
    J_n^n(t) = (-1)^n \sum_{j = 0}^n {n \choose j} (-1)^j \int_0^1 \frac{\frac{d^n}{dt^n}\left[x^{jt}\right]}{\ln^n(x)}\:dx \nonumber
\end{equation}
Here we note:
\begin{equation}
    \frac{d^n}{dt^n}\left[x^{jt}\right] = j^n \ln^n(x)x^{jt} \nonumber 
\end{equation}, 
Noting that for $j= 0$,  the derivative is $0$. Thus, 
\begin{equation}
    J_n^n(t) = (-1)^n \sum_{j = 1}^n {n \choose j} (-1)^j \int_0^1 \frac{j^n \ln^n(x)x^{jt}}{\ln^n(x)}\:dx = (-1)^n \sum_{j = 1}^n {n \choose j} (-1)^j j^n \int_0^1 x^{jt}\:dx  =  (-1)^n \sum_{j = 1}^n {n \choose j} (-1)^j \frac{j^n}{jt + 1}   \nonumber
\end{equation}
Where $J_n^k(0) = 0$ for $k = 0,\dots, n$.

Comment: An integral evaluation appears in the solution to a problem proposed by Cornel I. Valean in MathProblems Journal (Volume 5, Issue 3, 2015), pages 445-447 here: http://www.mathproblems-ks.org/?wpfb_dl=80

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I have a lot of work ahead of me to understand the paper. Happy though to see this integral has served interest in minds far more sophisticated than my own!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With
\begin{equation*}
 I_n = \int_{0}^{1}\left(\dfrac{x-1}{\ln(x)}\right)^n\, dx
\end{equation*}
and the substitution $x=e^{-y}$  we get that
\begin{equation*}
 I_n= \int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{f(y)}{y^n}\, dy
\end{equation*}
where 
\begin{equation*}
 f(y) = \left(1-e^{-y}\right)^ne^{-y} =\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}(-1)^{k}e^{-(k+1)y}.
\end{equation*}
Then $f(0)=0$ and $y=0$ is a zero of order $n$. Consequently $f^{(n-1)}(0)=0$. But
\begin{equation*}
 f^{(n-1)}(0)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}(-1)^{n+k-1}(k+1)^{n-1}=0.\tag{1}
\end{equation*}
Now we are prepared to evaluate $I_n$. After integration by parts $n-1$ times we have
\begin{gather*}
 I_n = \dfrac{1}{(n-1)!}\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{f^{(n-1)}(y)}{y}\, dy =\\[2ex] \dfrac{1}{(n-1)!}\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{y}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}(-1)^{n+k-1}(k+1)^{n-1}e^{-(k+1)y}\, dy.
\end{gather*}
However, if we use $(1)$ we get
\begin{gather*}
 I_n =  \dfrac{1}{(n-1)!}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}(-1)^{n+k-1}(k+1)^{n-1}\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{e^{-(k+1)y}-e^{-y}}{y}\, dy =\\[2ex]
 \dfrac{1}{(n-1)!}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}(-1)^{n+k}(k+1)^{n-1}\ln(k+1)
\end{gather*}
where we in the last step have used Frullani's integral.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frullani_integral

The integral
\begin{equation*}
 J_n(t) = \int_{0}^{1}\left(\dfrac{x^t-1}{\ln(x)}\right)^{n}\, dx =
\end{equation*}
can be treated similarly to $I_n$.
\begin{equation*}
J_n(t) =\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{g(y)}{y^n}\, dy
\end{equation*}
where 
\begin{equation*}
 g(y) = \left(1-e^{-ty}\right)^ne^{-y} =\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}(-1)^{k}e^{-(kt+1)y}.
\end{equation*}
Furthermore,
\begin{gather*}
 J_n(t) =  \dfrac{1}{(n-1)!}\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{g^{(n-1)}(y)}{y}\, dy =\\[2ex]
\dfrac{1}{(n-1)!}\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{g^{(n-1)}(y)-g^{(n-1)}(0)}{y}\, dy =\\[2ex]
\dfrac{1}{(n-1)!}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}(-1)^{n+k-1}(kt+1)^{n-1}\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{e^{-(k+1)y}-e^{-y}}{y}\, dy =\\[2ex]
\dfrac{1}{(n-1)!}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}(-1)^{n+k}(kt+1)^{n-1}\ln(kt+1).
\end{gather*}

Comment: Nice solution! (+1)

Comment: @JanG   Excellent Solution - I am writing a book of integrals for my Niece and I would like to reference you, can I contact you?

Comment: $@$Song Thank you.

Comment: $@$Kevin Nivek You are welcome. Via email?

Comment: @JanG - Which way you are comfortable with. My email is dp_galea@hotmail.com

Answer (score 8):

The general formula for $I_n$ is
$$
I_n = \frac 1 {(n-1)!}\sum_{k=1}^n {n \choose k} (-1)^{n-k} (k+1)^{n-1} \ln (k+1)
$$ and for $J_n(t)$, we have
$$
J_n(t) = \frac 1 {(n-1)!}\sum_{k=1}^n {n \choose k} (-1)^{n-k} (kt+1)^{n-1} \ln (kt+1).
$$ I've checked that this formula returns correct values
\begin{align*}
I_1 =& \ln 2\\
I_2 =& - 4\ln 2 + 3\ln 3\\
I_3 =& 22\ln 2 -\frac{27}{2}\ln 3\\
I_4 =& -\frac{272}{3} \ln 2 + 27\ln 3 +\frac {125}6 \ln 5.
\end{align*} **Evaluation of $I_n$:** To see this, we first make change of variable $ y = -\ln x$ to find that
\begin{align*}
I_n = & \int_0^\infty \left(\frac{1-e^{-y}}{y}\right)^n e^{-y} \mathrm dy \\
=& \int_0^\infty \left(\int_0^1 e^{-vy} \mathrm dv\right)^n e^{-y} \mathrm dy \\
=& \int_0^\infty \int_0^1 \cdots \int_0^1 e^{-y(1+v_1+v_2 + \cdots +v_n)} \mathrm dv_1\cdots \mathrm d v_n \mathrm dy \\
=& \int_0^1 \cdots \int_0^1 \frac 1 { 1+ v_1 + \cdots +v_n} \mathrm dv_1 \cdots \mathrm dv_n.
\end{align*}
To calculate $I_n$ iteratively, let us define
\begin{align*}
F_n(x) := \int_0^x \int_0^{x_{n-1}} \cdots \int_0^{x_1} \frac 1 {1+t} \mathrm dt \mathrm dx_1\cdots \mathrm dx_{n-1} .
\end{align*} We can find that for $n\ge 1$,
$$
F_n(x) = \frac {(x+1)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}\ln (x+1) - \frac{H_{n-1}}{(n-1)!}(x+1)^{n-1}
$$ where $ H_n = 1+ \frac 1 2 + \cdots + \frac 1n$ is the $n$-th harmonic number. (I skipped the derivation, but given the form we can at least check that $F_n' = F_{n-1}$ and $F_1(x) = \ln (x+1)$. So mathematical induction can be applied.)

For convenience let us introduce the noation $F$ for the forward opeartor
$
\displaystyle F[f](x) = f(x+1)
$ and the forward difference operator 
$
\displaystyle D[f](x) = F[f](x) - I[f](x) = f(x+1)- f(x)
$ where $f$ is an arbitrary function. Note that these are linear operators, and we write $D^n = (F-I)^n $ as the iteration of $D$. Now, since $\displaystyle \int D[f] = D\left[\int f\right] + C$, we can integrate $I_n$ iteratively;
\begin{align*}
I_n = &\int_0^1  \cdots \int_0^1 \frac 1 { 1+ v_1 + \cdots +v_n} \mathrm dv_1 \cdots \mathrm dv_n\\
=& \int_0^1  \cdots \int_0^1 \left[F_1(v_1+v_2+\cdots +v_n)\right]^{v_1=1}_{v_1=0}\mathrm dv_2 \cdots \mathrm dv_n\\
=& \int_0^1  \cdots \int_0^1 D[F_1](v_2+\cdots +v_n)\mathrm dv_2 \cdots \mathrm dv_n \\
=& \int_0^1  \cdots \int_0^1 \left[D[F_2](v_2+\cdots +v_n)\right]^{v_2=1}_{v_2=0}\mathrm dv_3 \cdots \mathrm dv_n \\
=& \int_0^1  \cdots \int_0^1 D^2[F_2](v_3+\cdots +v_n) \mathrm dv_3 \cdots \mathrm dv_n \\
=& \cdots \int_0^1  D ^{n-1} [F_{n-1}](v_n)\mathrm dv_n\\
=& \left[ D^{n-1} [F_n](v_n)\right]^{v_n=1}_{v_n=0}\\
=& D^n[F_n](0).
\end{align*}
We notice that $\displaystyle D^k[x^{k-j}] \equiv 0$ for $j\ge 1$, i.e. polynomials of degree less than $k$ becomes $0$ when $k$-times differenced (because its degree decreases by $1$ each time it is differenced.) So we have
\begin{align*}
D^n [F_n](x) =& D^n\left [\frac {(x+1)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}\ln (x+1) - \frac{H_{n-1}}{(n-1)!}(x+1)^{n-1}\right] \\
=& D^n\left [\frac {(x+1)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}\ln (x+1)\right] -0 \\
=& (F-I)^n \left [\frac {(x+1)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}\ln (x+1)\right] \\\\
=& \sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} F^k (-I)^{n-k} \left [\frac {(x+1)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}\ln (x+1)\right]\\
=& \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} (-1)^{n-k} \frac {(x+k+1)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}\ln (x+k+1).
\end{align*} Therefore, it follows that
$$
I_n = D^n[F_n](0) = \frac 1 {(n-1)!}\sum_{k=1}^n {n\choose k} (-1)^{n-k} (k+1)^{n-1} \ln (k+1).
$$ 
**Addendum, Evaluation of $J_n(t)$:** The same change of variable $y = -\ln x$ gives us that
$$
J_n(t) = \int_0^t \cdots \int_0^t \frac 1 { 1+v_1 + \cdots +v_n} \mathrm dv_1 \cdots \mathrm dv_n.
$$ Nothing really changes except that we now define $t$-step forward and forward difference as
\begin{align*}
\hat F[f](x) =& f(x+t)\\
\hat D[f](x) = & \hat F[f](x) - I[f](x) = f(x+t) - f(x).
\end{align*} Then,
\begin{align*}
J_n(t) = &\int_0^t  \cdots \int_0^t \frac 1 { 1+ v_1 + \cdots +v_n} \mathrm dv_1 \cdots \mathrm dv_n\\
=& \int_0^t  \cdots \int_0^t \left[F_1(v_1+v_2+\cdots +v_n)\right]^{t}_{v_1=0}\mathrm dv_2 \cdots \mathrm dv_n\\
=& \int_0^t  \cdots \int_0^t \hat D[F_1](v_2+\cdots +v_n)\mathrm dv_2 \cdots \mathrm dv_n \\
=& \int_0^t  \cdots \int_0^t \left[\hat D[F_2](v_2+\cdots +v_n)\right]^{t}_{v_2=0}\mathrm dv_3 \cdots \mathrm dv_n \\
=& \int_0^t  \cdots \int_0^t \hat D^2[F_2](v_3+\cdots +v_n) \mathrm dv_3 \cdots \mathrm dv_n \\
=& \cdots = \int_0^t \hat D ^{n-1} [F_{n-1}](v_n)\mathrm dv_n\\
=& \left[\hat D^{n-1} [F_n](v_n)\right]^t_{v_n=0}\\
=& \hat D^n[F_n](0).
\end{align*} Since
\begin{align*}
\hat D^n [F_n](x) =&\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} \hat F^k (-I)^{n-k} \frac {(x+1)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}\ln (x+1)\\
=&\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}  (-1)^{n-k} \frac {(x+kt+1)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}\ln (x+kt+1)
\end{align*} it follows
$$
J_n(t) = \left[\hat D^n [F_n](x)\right]_{x=0} = \frac 1 {(n-1)!}\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}  (-1)^{n-k} (kt+1)^{n-1}\ln (kt+1).
$$